# PHP seems to be evaluating an if statement backwards

Tags: php, operator-precedence

So I have a PHP statement of the following type:

`if ($x=function($y) || $z == 50) {`

What I see happening is that if $z is 50, $x doesn't get set because the function is never called.
Is that really possible?  I can (and did) fix this easily, but I guess I am confused that that's what is happening and want to make sure I don't make mistakes like this going forward 
I tried to find out how OR expressions like this are evaluated.  Is there a place I can look to see how php gets "compiled"?

Comment: IMHO it's good practice to swap tests - let `$z == 50` be first. It it passes, we do not need to call the function.

Comment: Conditions are evaluated from left to right. Full code example or didn't happen.

Comment: As seen in the answers below, conditions are not evaluated from left to right, they are evaluated in order of precedence.

Comment: @watcher s/conditions/expressions/

Comment: @Danack you're not suggesting that this topic has been covered before, are you? ;)

Answer (score 16):

You have operator precedence issue. Check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Because `||` has higher precedence than `=` Your expression really looks like this

```
if ( 
    $x = ( 
        function($y) || ( $z == 50 ) 
    ) 
)
```

Instead of (what I think was your intention)

```
if ( 
    ($x = function($y)) || ($z == 50) 
)
```

Comment: Sorry, just a few seconds too slow ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Good answer is never too slow

Comment: Yes, indeed, this is exactly it!  Ugh, I thought I had even tried adding paranthesis to make it work, but must have gotten it wrong.  Seems so simple (and stupid of me) now! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`||` has [higher precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than `=`, which means your expression becomes:

```
$x = (foo($y) || ($z == 50));
```

This means that `$x` will always be either `true` or `false`. Nothing else.

Try:

```
if( ($x = foo($y)) || ($z == 50))
```

Or, more readable:

```
$x = foo($y);
if( $x || $z == 50)
```